# React Prototype: Problem with Rendering Maps and Charts

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to learn react by doing prototype.Can you let me know why maps and charts are not showing properly.
I debugged but still no luck. Providing my code below

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/analytics-xj9fz5?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FGoogleMapComponent.tsx%3A17%2C44

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BarChart, Bar, XAxis, YAxis, Tooltip, CartesianGrid } from "recharts";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { RootState, AppActions } from "../store/types"; // Import types
import { updateDateRange } from "../store/actions"; // Sample action import

interface SalesData {
  date: string;
  sales: number;
}

interface ChartProps {
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
}

const salesData = [
  { date: "2023-02-05", sales: 1500 },
  { date: "2023-02-06", sales: 2300 },
  { date: "2023-02-07", sales: 1200 },
  // More data...
];

const SalesChart: React.FC<ChartProps> = ({}) => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());

  const filteredData = salesData.filter((item) => {
    const itemDate = new Date(item.date);
    return itemDate >= startDate && itemDate <= endDate;
  });

  return (
    // ... Chart Rendering ...

    <div>
      <h2>Sales Chart</h2>
      <div className="date-filter">
        <DatePicker
          selected={startDate}
          onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
        />
        <DatePicker selected={endDate} onChange={(date) => setEndDate(date)} />
      </div>

      <BarChart width={600} height={300} data={filteredData}>
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis dataKey="date" />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip />
        <Bar dataKey="sales" fill="#8884d8" />
      </BarChart>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  startDate: state.startDate,
  endDate: state.endDate,
});

// Redux mapStateToProps etc. (TypeScript needs some work here depending on your Redux setup)

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SalesChart);
```

Comment: Please [edit] to specify/clarify what exactly "not showing properly" means to you in this context. What is rendered/shown versus what you are expecting to be rendered/shown? The linked sandbox also isn't accessible, did you remember to save the code and make the sandbox public?

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for your response, I have updated my sandbox. salesData array of objects is not showing in the graph

Comment: The data graphs seem to be working for me. You *do* realize the dates in the data are from February of ***last*** year, 2023, not 2024, right?

Comment: @Drew I changed the date but still bar chart not showing properly, can you let me know how to fix the date picker too

Comment: Well, I saw the chart render data, but I have no idea what you mean when you say it isn't showing properly. Can you [edit] the post to describe in better detail what isn't correct about the chart and what you are expecting?